# How to access a class's state variables outside the class in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a method `addUFInput` outside my screen class `UltrafiltrationScreen` which I call to store some inputs into my Firebase FireStore. These inputs are stored in `UltrafiltrationScreen`'s state and are set by the user using input sliders:

```
export default class UltrafiltrationScreen extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      before: 60, after: 60
    }
```

```
export const addUFInput = () => {
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    const uid = user.uid;
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    const UFRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('Ultrafiltration').doc(timestamp.toString());
    UFRef.set({
      before: UltrafiltrationScreen.getBefore(),
      after: UltrafiltrationScreen.getAfter(),
      timestamp
    });

  }
};
```

I'm not exactly sure how to access the state's `before` and `after` variables from my `addUFInput` method. I've tried creating static methods `getBefore` and `getAfter` to return the state but these do not work since `static` functions can't access the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Async Storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) to store data and then retrieve in your function.

example code :

```
 storeUltrafiltrationValues = async()=>{
  const {before,after}=this.state;
  AsyncStorage.setItem('Ultrafiltration', JSON.stringify({before,after}))
}
```

in addUFInput function

```
export const addUFInput = async() => {
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    const uid = user.uid;
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    const data=JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('UltrafiltrationScreen'));
    const UFRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('Ultrafiltration').doc(timestamp.toString());
    UFRef.set({
      before: data.before,
      after: data.after,
      timestamp
    });

  }
};
```